# Best way to wait for SqlClient calls in ASP.Net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, async-await, sqlclient

I created an SPA application with Angular frontend and ASP.Net Core 3.1 backend. I use a typical RESTful API for communicating between the two, along with a SignalR based WebSocket API for some real-time push status updates. Because this application is a rewrite of an older Windows .NET program, I have a substantial codebase that uses SqlClient to interact with a common database. I want to reuse this code and not try to convert the system to EF. I have all of this working but I became worried about how calls to function s like ExecuteScalar, ExecuteReader and ExecuteNonQuery might negatively impact the performance of an ASP.Net backend running in IIS. I also need to consider GetDataAdapter and adapter.Fill but that is a different issue.

It seems I should be using Async calls to help thread management but if all I do is immediately Await the call is there any difference to using the synchronous calls? Do the synchronous calls wait nicely in IIS?

To be clear, I haven't seen any problems using synchronous or asynchronous calls. My early testing isn't under load. I would like my app to scale up to about a hundred concurrent users, maybe with a cloud host. This is why I want to get the basic architectural decision right.

If it matters, my backend runs without change in .NET 5 but I haven't committed to the upgrade yet. If .NET 5 can benefit my performance I will consider the upgrade.

Comment: You can improve the capacity of your webserver by making the database calls async, as long as the controller actions which trigger them are also async - because it frees up the IIS worker thread while the database call is running. So if you server is at or near capacity then you might notice some improvements immediately, or at least it frees up capacity for future expansion.

Comment: If your entry code is `async`, it's best to use ADO.NET Asynchronous calls, to avoid mixing synchronous and asynchronous code. Almost all ADO.NET functions have asynchronous equivalents. More detail in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming. The performance improvements may or may not be noticed immediately - that depends on your load; main benefit is avoiding the blocking of a ThreadPool thread while waiting on the database call to complete. See https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was spending significant time making all of the database access asynchronous (including converting a large number of GetDataAdapter-adapter.Fill calls into ExecuteReader.ReadAsync calls) then I became concerned that I was wasting my time. Surely, the synchronous calls don't spin when they wait, do they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if all I do is immediately Await the call is there any difference to using the synchronous calls?

Yes, there's a very significant difference: it releases the thread so that instead of being blocked on network IO (and whatever your database server is doing), that thread can go and do other interesting things. Await is all about scalability of CPU resources (and in particular: threads), but there are some minor overheads involved which can make *individual* requests slightly slower, but not by any amount you'd ever measure.

But for context: Stack Overflow (which has much higher load than that) scales fine on IIS (it also runs in Kestrel
of desired) using *mostly* synchronous database access (the conversion to asynchronous data access is still in progress). If your app doesn't scale to 100 users, blaming sync vs async would be passing the buck: the real problem is probably bad query performance due to suboptimal design. Async won't be the thing that makes or breaks that - it'll just help a well designed system scale even further.

Comment: Thanks for the input. So the synchronous calls don't sleep when they wait? Or do they have some other behavior that hurts multi-thread performace? This would be the only case I could think of where the Async calls might perform better.

Comment: My understanding is that each REST API call is executed on a dedicated thread and the controller context is dedicated to that call until it is resolved. That is why I consider the synchronous calls acceptable, as long as they don't do something bad like spinlock.

Comment: @user2242061 " So the synchronous calls don't sleep when they wait? "...that's one way of putting it. `await` allows the calling code to be "paused" effectively, and the thread it was running on released for other code to use. Meanwhile i the code being awaited is doing a non-CPU-bound operation e.g. a network or database call, it isn't using a thread that IIS could use. Whereas in a totally synchronous setup everything runs on the single thread and that thread isn't released even when the code is currently doing a non-CPU-bound operation.

Comment: Wow. That's great to know. I will continue converting the synchronous calls to asynchronous.

Comment: @user2242061 to put it another way: threads are relatively expensive, so the system tries not to have too many of them; if they are blocking waiting on IO, you can't service additional requests. It is a cold wait (sleep), not a hot wait (loop), but the effect is the same: the thread is useless. Await (async) solves that problem by unwinding the thread, letting it do useful work instead, without needing additional threads. You get more work for the same thread count.

Comment: That's what I finally understood thanks to you and @ADyson. Releasing the thread means suspending the current execution context and letting the thread switch to another context that is no longer blocked. Multiplying the effect of a limited pool of threads to handle many times more concurrent tasks. This really helped my understanding of how SqlClient and Async-Await works in ASP.Net. Thanks.